# Use external function in express.js middleware

Tags: express

How can I access some function from the outside world in the middleware? For example, if I need to check some part of request and set `locals`.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if (myfunc(req)) {    // <-- how should I load this function to be accessible here?
        res.locals.myvar = true;
    }
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

At the head of that file you'd want to import a custom module:

`var myfunc = require('./path/to/myfunc/module')`

That file would look like:

```
var myfunc = function(req) {
  // Do something.
}

module.exports = myfunc;
```

Then, you should just be able to call: `myfunc(req);`

Further information on [Custom NodeJS Modules](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders).